# After adding "Options -MultiViews" URL Rewrite - $_GET variable not passing through

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a simple rewrite that changes

```
http://blog.website.com/post.php?linkcheck=dkdkdk
```

into

```
http://blog.website.com/post/2s33dd
```

using the following rewrite

```
 Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ ./post.php?linkcheck=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The rewrite works, it displays the page (i don't get a 404), but it doesn't appear to be passing through the GET['action'] from the URL.

Trying to remove cookie and window.href.replace it nothing happens, cookie still present.

I saw a post that suggested i put `Options -MultiViews` still does not respond too the GET parameter

```
   <?php 
if (isset($_GET['action'])){
if ($_GET['action'] == "logout"){ ?>
<?php
setcookie("blog_id", "", time() - 3600); //cookie not being removed
?>
<script>window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('?action=logout', '')</script>
   <?php    
    }   
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: Where are you passing `$_GET['action']`? Also use the QSA flag.

Comment: Also the code at the bottom, is sooo left its just not right!

Comment: @lawrencecherone I have editted my code, and added QSA as a stack post suggested, but it removes cookie for https://blog.website.com/post not https://blog.website.com/